# Show that $2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+45=0$ has no real roots

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I tried solving the above question but was unable to prove it.
I used Descartes rule of sign, factorisation techniques, and many other things but could not figure out the solution.

Comment: @Hendrix: mh, as the leading coefficient is positive and the polynomial is said to have no real roots, this is not a great discovery.

Comment: @Hendrix That's a rather pointless statement, since that is precisely what needs to be shown.

Comment: Have you tried to factor the polynomial's derivative?

Comment: @RobertShore: is this simpler ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know whether it's simpler.  It just seemed like a relatively quick idea that was worth trying.  My question mark was genuine, not a disguised hint.

Answer (score 8):

First note$$2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+45=2(x^3+3x^2)^2+12\left(x^2+\tfrac52 x\right)^2+5(x+3)^2.$$Not only is this non-negative, but it could only be zero if$$x^3+3x^2=x^2+\tfrac52 x=x+3=0.$$The last condition simplifies to $x=-3$, which contradicts the second condition.

Comment: How did you get this magical decomposition ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I used up the $x^6,\,x^5$ terms with a perfect square, and noted the remaining $x^4$ coefficient was positive. I then mopped up the remaining $x^4,\,x^3$ terms in the same way, and got a perfect square left over. (I double-checked my arithmetic at the end on Wolfram Alpha.) Nothing magical about it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to make perfect cube and completely forgot about perfect square

Comment: @user456230 Perfect cubes aren't non-negative unless you're cubing a non-negative, so it sounds like you were trying to cube a quadratic of non-positive discriminant. With problems like these, you should always start by trying to write a sum of squares.

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Comment: Assuming you don’t know the polynomial is nonnegative, how does the last statement by itself prove that there are absolutely no real roots? Would you not have to check $0$ and $-5/2$ as well in the same manner?

Comment: As I was curious, I tried this method for some other polynomials to see if it was universal, either by subtracting $(x^n+ax^{n-1})^2$ or more terms $(x^n+ax^{n-1}+bx^{n-2}+...)^2$, but we are not systematically left with another positive polynomial. As if the method and the polynomial were destined to work together.

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown The point is comparison of the roots of the quantities squared shows they're never $0$ simultaneously, so the sum of their squares must be positive.

Comment: @zwim Well, obviously it only works for polynomials that can't be negative on $\Bbb R$. Even for those that can't, you may need to experiment with which terms you take out simultaneously. On the other hand, it's easy to sum squares to invent a problem like this backwards, then see whether other people can work out the decomposition that solves them.

Answer (score 2):

Factor $x^4$ and separate a non-negative part of the expression covering completely the terms $x^6$ and $x^5,$ then factor $x^2,$ ...
$$\begin{aligned}P(x)=&2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+45\\=&2x^4(x^2+6x+9)+12x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+45\\=&2x^4(x^2+6x+9)+3x^2(4x^2+20x+25)+30x^2+30x+45\\=&2x^4(x^2+6x+9)+3x^2(4x^2+20x+25)+15(2x^2+2x+3)\end{aligned}$$ which is strictly positive for any real $x.$

Answer (score 1):

$2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+80x^2+30x+4$

Can be factored into:

$
2x^4(x^2 + 6x + 9) + 12x^2(x^2 + 5x + \frac{25}{4}) + 5(x^2+6x+9)
= 0
$

$=2x^4(x+3)^2 +12x^2(x+\frac{5}{2})^2 +5(x+3)^2 = 0$

But this is not possible for real $x$