# Show that $p(x)=2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+8x^2+30x+45$ has no real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, roots

The following question appears in a book for high school students who do not know any calculus but know the basic theory of polynomials:

> Show that the equation $$p(x)=2x^6+12x^5+30x^4+60x^3+8x^2+30x+45=0$$ has no real roots.

---

**My thoughts:**

Clearly it has no positive real roots. I guess the idea is to group the terms so that each grouping is a positive function for negative $x$. But I could not find such a grouping.

Another observation is that $p(x) - 2(x+1)^6 = 20x^3 + 50x^2 + 18x + 43$. If we could show $(1-x)^6 < -10x^3 + 25x^2 -9x + 21$ for all positive $x$ we will be done. But I could not show that as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is unfortunately false; $p(-1) = -17$, but $p(0) = 45$, so there must be a root in $(-1,0)$.

Comment: And as $\lim_{x\to -\infty} p(-x) \to +\infty$ there must be a root in $(-\infty, -1)$.

Comment: @Isomorphism If it helps, the *two* real (and negative) roots are approximately $-4.102$ and $-0.845$ :)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately there was a typo in my question. Let me post a new question.

Comment: The actual question has been answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312367/show-that-2x612x530x460x380x230x45-0-has-no-real-roots

Comment: @Isomorphism  Why'd you ask a new question rather than edit an existing question.

Comment: I didn't ask that question. It was already there.